# How can I compare dependencies with a remote pom file?

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

We have a maven project which is part of a microservice environment. I want to find out about the latest versions of dependencies (before the release) and update my `pom.xml` file based on that.

Before, I was using this command:

```
mvn versions:compare-dependencies -DremotePom=group:artifact:version -DupdatePropertyVersions=true -DupdateDependencies=true
```

But now, our process is changed and we don't have a built version on our repository before the release and I need something like this:

```
mvn versions:compare-dependencies -DremotePomFile=http://someurl.com/path/to/our/sourcecontrol/pom.xml -DupdatePropertyVersions=true -DupdateDependencies=true
```

Is there any solution to use the `versions` plugin with a remote file instead of a remote pom from a repository?

Comment: If you put a version in your pom that does not exist in the repository, the build will fail. Why do you want that?

Comment: Did you try ```mvn versions:display-dependency-updates```?

Comment: @JFMeier it's complicated. The versions of the dependencies available in the repository but the build version of the final product is not there before the release. I want to compare dependencies with the final product and update them inside my service which is one of the services inside the final product.

Comment: I just say: If you update a dependency to e.g. 2.0.0 but 2.0.0 does not exist yet in the repository, your IDE will probably show an error and if you try to build, you get an error as well. It seems much better to first build 2.0.0 and then change the version of the dependency.

Comment: the version of the dependency is there and available in the repository but the version of the collector of the dependencies is not there. The remotePom which I want to compare with that is not there yet.

Comment: if you want latest versions, why don't you just use a goal like `versions:use-latest-releases` ?

Comment: latest is not the version that we want always. I want to update to the exact versions for the next release which is not the latest version always.

Comment: Then I guess you need to write your own plugin, or establish an automatic release process of your remotePom (e.g. as snapshot version).